# How to localize iMovie projects

Tags: ios, automator, imovie

I'm working on App Previews for my iOS application in iMovie. It contains video footage from device with Disclaimer titles below. I'm looking for a way to localize disclaimer titles. I have 3 videos with 3-5 disclaimers in English and 11 more languages I want to localize it to. Quite a lot of monkey job. Is there a way to automate localization process?